# Living document for replication of SQL Server Tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've been tasked to create an internal site for my company to document the replication of tables in our databases. I'd like to make the site dynamic, but to do this I'd need to query sql server to figure out how each table replicates. I know you can query sql server to figure out things like column names and many other features, can you query sql server to determine how a table replicates, and if so is there a good document to show me how or get me started? We're running sql server 2005 and c# or tsql are the preferred languages for me to use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking a look at the documentation for the syspublications and syssubscriptions system views in the Distribution database.  Does that provide you with the information you need to build your site? If not, what else are you looking for? I've included links to the documentation for those views below.

[syspublications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189805%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

[syssubscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188931%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I also found this [site](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1808) so between your links and this I can probably figure it out.